# Prevent javascript execution when page is only preloaded by hovering a href link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page (call it page **B**) with some Javascript code, running Ajax calls to the backend.

My problem is the the javascript is executed when user is on page **A**, and hovers the link to page **B** (the browser seems to make a GET request, to preload the next page). Is there any way to make sure the javascript on page **B** is only executed on a "real" visit?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Run script
});
</script
```

Comment: i'd make the page listen to a get parameter like `preview`. Then, on hover you can add that parameter to the url. Without it behaves normally, with no js is executed